# Converting a string to nltk.Tree

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I want to construct a parse tree from a given string. For example: "The cat ate a cookie".
While there are two methods to construct a tree
using

```
from nltk import Tree
Tree(S, [Tree(NP, ..), Tree(VP,..)])
```

or using fromstring method which accepts the labeled bracketing format as a string:

```
fromstring('(S (NP (DT the) (NN cat)) (VP (VBD ate) (NP (DT a) (NN cookie))))')
```

But to use the fromstring method, I need to define a grammar which can return the labeled bracketing which the fromstring method accepts.

I don't know how to define the right grammar. So is there any built in method that I can use to generate the labeled bracketing of any sentence/list of words?
To put it differently, is there a generalized grammar defined in nltk which I can use to produce the label bracketing?

Comment: try to work through this chapter: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html

Comment: @alvas Question arose after reading that chapter.